# Combine web site app and windows forms app in one solution in visual studio 2013 (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, web-applications, mvp, windows

I've created windows forms app, where I've devided code into MVP layers - presenter and view. I've created two classes WinView and ConsoleView, that implement IView interface, so I can run my app in winform mode and console mode. Now I want to make a web port of my View layer, I've added an empty website into my solution, but I don't know how to connect default.aspx.cs with MainPresenter.cs. At the end I want to have Win and Web versions of my app, which use same libraries or something, I'm in C# and Visual Studio for about one and a half months, so I'm not enough delved into it yet.

Comment: Please add some more code, especially the `IView` interface. You could try to implement `IView` in the codebehind file `default.aspx.cs`; however programming models sometimes differ significantly between client and web applications. Showing `IView` in your question might help to point those out in the answer.

Comment: Oh, I've figured it out. I've moved MainPresenter.cs into a separate class library project, and added a reference in website project and winform project to it ))